# ruby: ECONNREFUSED from http.rb

Tags: ruby, http, connection

I am trying to parse an rss feed with Ruby. This is my (working) code, with the actual feed url:

```
include 'rss'

myfeed = RSS::Parser.parse('http://allmusicnews.altervista.org/blog/feed/', false)
```

If I run it from my development computer (Mac OS 10.9), all works fine. If I run it from my server (Debian 7), all i get is:

```
/home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) for "allmusicnews.altervista.org" port 80 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:318:in `open_http'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:736:in `buffer_open'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:211:in `block in open_loop'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:209:in `catch'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:209:in `open_loop'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:150:in `open_uri'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:716:in `open'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:724:in `read'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rss/parser.rb:103:in `normalize_rss'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rss/parser.rb:89:in `initialize'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rss/parser.rb:76:in `new'
from /home/daniele/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rss/parser.rb:76:in `parse'
```

This does not happen with other rss feeds. example: feeds.blogo.it/soundsblog/it seems working well on both platforms.

I am using the same Ruby version (2.2.0), installed with RVM on both the computers. Same gems too.

Any clue, at least about what to look for?

ps: it may seem something related to connection timeout, but as I run my script suddenly I see the error message above, there's no idle waiting time...

Comment: Did you see http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS.html#module-RSS-label-Consuming+RSS ?

Comment: Is there an ENV that is set on your machine or the server?

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore my question. I was shooting to the wrong target.

Actually I'm afraid to have some blacklistish problem with my production machine. I cannot connect to altervista.org server in any way (lynx, telnet), I keep getting "connection refused error", so there's nothing to do with my Ruby code...